# Story about a medieval railroad built by a blacksmith involving time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I am looking for the title/author of a short story I read in the 70's. It dealt with a railroad built and operated by a blacksmith and his daughter. A time patrol is sent there to investigate whether it is an interference from a rogue time traveler.

Sounds like a "Time Patrol"/Poul Anderson story but I couldn't find it in there...

Comment: Rings a vague bell. I think I might have read it in a 1950s Galaxy.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this (unanswered) question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213415/short-story-about-a-railroad-and-a-steam-engine-in-medieval-times