# short story about a railroad and a steam engine in medieval times

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

In the early 70's I read this short story in an anthology.

A time patrol team must inquire about a railroad in the medieval English countryside. It turns out that a local blacksmith did invent a steam engine and established a transportation service.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This sounds interesting.  You might be able to improve your question by reviewing the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.  For example, do you recall what the cover looked like?

Comment: There is [another question very similar to this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202310/story-about-a-medieval-railroad-built-by-a-blacksmith-involving-time-travel), unfortunatelly unanswered as of yet.